# What do I have to disable in order to prevent poor font rendering in IE8 using the jquery Isotope plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, fonts, jquery-isotope

I'm using Desandro's isotope plugin that is working lilke a charm except that the text is rendering poorly in IE8.

As don't care about other browsers at the moment, is there a way to fix this? 
If not, what functionnality shoud I disable in order to prevent this?

You can see some examples and more explanations here: [Problem with poor font rendering with CSS3 transitions, jQuery, & Google Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136698/problem-with-poor-font-rendering-with-css3-transitions-jquery-google-fonts)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Isotope's author on font rendering issues here](http://desandro.github.com/motion-emotion/) scrolling down to "Pitfalls and issues". I remember the issue being related to the CSS transitions and that providing a background colour seemed to solve the issue. Also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136698/problem-with-poor-font-rendering-with-css3-transitions-jquery-google-fonts) may point you towards a solution; the issue there was also CSS transitions related, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is an IE issue, try implementing Google Chrome Frame

Comment: Sadly this is not an option :(